# How to compare to cells and return a particular cell value in the matched row in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on some classification task, but my data in both classes(class-0, class-1) is not balanced. so I added some synthetic data to make both classes balanced.

I performed some classification using the new data and now I have to remove the synthetic data to only retain the scores of Original Data to predict the accuracy of the model.

Here is some sample Data:

```
score   New Data             Original Data

0.004   (0.448038,0.696787) (0.242376,0.603979)

0.008   (0.207888,0.921134) (0.448038,0.696787)

0.001   (0.371334,0.498577) (0.436265,0.947961)

0       (0.242376,0.603979) 

0.001   (0.209049,0.909077) 

0       (0.436265,0.947961)
```

Now the goal is to compare the cell contents in `C column` with `B column` and if a match is found, I need to collect the corresponding scores in `A column`

So, the desired output is:

```
score
0
0.004
0
```

to show clearly for reference the matching rows:

```
score   New Data             Original Data

0       (0.242376,0.603979) (0.242376,0.603979)

0.004   (0.448038,0.696787) (0.448038,0.696787)

0       (0.436265,0.947961) (0.436265,0.947961)
```

I have little experience with excel functions, Any help will greatly save my time.

Thanks,

Gopi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In D2:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(C2,B:B,0))
```

Then copy/drag down.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Works greatt!!

Comment: Aww, boo! I had a nice array formula all ready to post...then you do it much more simply. :D  (I had `=INDEX($A$2:$A$7,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$7=C2,ROW($B$2:$B$7)-ROW($B$2)+1),ROWS($B$2:B$2)))` ...  :O  ).  Why didn't I think index/match would do it? Quick thinking.

Comment: @BruceWayne I find myself overthinking the problem many times, also.  Can't tell you how many times I have come up with a beautiful array type formula only to have someone do it with SUMIFS().

Comment: I am just realizing of how complicated functions excel can do, thanks..

Comment: I need to just tape ["K.I.S.S."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) to my monitors :P